# Buildroot error compiling : Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority

Tags: linux, certificate, buildroot

I am new to Buildroot and trying to make an image of an embedded Linux, including python3 and some modules (lxml, numpy).

To begin with, I am just trying to create an image and download it on my ZedBoard.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.blaess.fr/christophe/buildroot-lab/index.html#I) (explanations are in french, sorry. You can check the commands thought), trying to apply it to my needs (ZedBoard instead of Raspberry pi 4 and adding Python3 and my packages).

Finally, when I run the "make" command, the complitation goes on for like 40 minutes and ends with these errors (my actual logs are partly in french so I tried to translate them. It might be a bit different from the english logs...):

```
>>> linux-headers 4.16 Downloading

-2021-09-29 15:39:16--  https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.16.tar.xz
Resolution of proxy-surf.loc.cnes.fr (proxy-surf.loc.cnes.fr)... 10.135.8.20
Connexion to proxy-surf.loc.cnes.fr (proxy-surf.loc.cnes.fr)|10.135.8.20|:8050... connected.
ERROR : unable to verify the attribute cdn.kernel.org of the certificate, emitted by «CN=tu-proxysurf-p01.cnes.fr,OU=AC Deleguee,OU=0002 775665912,OU=0002 775665912,O=CNES,C=FR» :
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To establish an unsecured connexion to cdn.kernel.org, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2021-09-29 15:39:17--  http://sources.buildroot.net/linux/linux-4.16.tar.xz
Resolution of proxy-surf.loc.cnes.fr (proxy-surf.loc.cnes.fr)... 10.135.8.20
Connexion to proxy-surf.loc.cnes.fr (proxy-surf.loc.cnes.fr)|10.135.8.20|:8050... connected.
Proxy request transmitted, waiting for answer... 404 Not Found
2021-09-29 15:39:17 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2021-09-29 15:39:17--  http://sources.buildroot.net/linux-4.16.tar.xz
Resolution of proxy-surf.loc.cnes.fr (proxy-surf.loc.cnes.fr)... 10.135.8.20
Connexion to proxy-surf.loc.cnes.fr (proxy-surf.loc.cnes.fr)|10.135.8.20|:8050... connected.
Proxy request transmitted, waiting for answer... 404 Not Found
2021-09-29 15:39:17 ERROR 404: Not Found.

make[1]: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:148 : /home/ouriacc/workspace/BuildRoot/build-zb/build/linux-headers-4.16/.stamp_downloaded] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:23 : _all] Error 2
```

So far I have tried installing, updating and upgrading the ca-certificates but it didn't change a thing...
Could someone please tell me what I can do to remove these errors ?

**EDIT :** I tried going to the URLs that the logs return and for the last 2 of them there actually isn't anything to see there except a 404 NOT FOUND error. Does that mean that the compiler is not up to date as it looks for something that doesn't exist anymore or ?....

**NEW EDIT :** Actually the certificate thing is no big deal. I fixed it by adding --no-check-certificate in the Config.in file (the one in the buildroot folder !) at the WGET line as follows :

```
config BR2_WGET
       string "wget command"
       default "wget --passive-ftp -nd -t 3 --no-check-certificate"
```

However that's not the actual problem. Check my solution in the answer below to fix it.

Comment: It would be hard to give you a definite answer without more infos. For a starter, what version of Buildroot are you using and what is the defconfig you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM EDIT:

After some investigation, I found out that my question doesn't have the right title. It should rather have been something like "Buildroot - 404 error not found".
The actual problem is that my buildroot tries to download .tar.xz files to build the linux image but the URL to which it goes to download them doesn't exist anymore (you can observ it's not even in the linux index : http://sources.buildroot.net/linux/ ) Most likely, the provider of the linux-4.16 stopped providing it. So obviously, buildroot can't finish it's work !

SOLUTION :

I went into my buildroot folder. Then I edited my board's configuration file. For me it was `zynq_zed_defconfig`. So I ran :

```
gedit ./configs/zynq_zed_defconfig
```

Then I modified the file to make it point to an available version of linux, existing in the index (link above) (4.16.1 for example). I only edited the following variables :

```
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_LINUX_HEADERS_CUSTOM_4_16_1=y
BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_VERSION_VALUE="4.16.1"
```

I saved my changes then ran `make zynq_zed_defconfg` to update the configuration and finally I could run `make` again and fix the error !

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard answering you without more info, however, for the 404s it is most likely that you have an outdated defconfig/version of buildroot.

For the wget SSL errors, you can try multiple solutions:

- Updating your openssl library version (aka. udpate openssl) + compare your ca-certificates version with the latest one: (20210603-1 for ArchLinux).
- Update wget too.

Alternatively, but unsecure too:
You can add the necessary option for wget in the configuration, to bypass the error.

Build options -> Commands -> Wget command.
Add "--no-check-certificate" to the options already
present there. That will make it ignore all self-signed certificates.
The problem is that this is an insecure solution as you cannot be sure the file buildroot is downloading is legitimate is isn't a malware.

Finally, it seems you are using some sort of proxy, or something that differs you DNS resolution. You could try testing if that's the case by changing DNS provider/removing proxy/testing other internet provider (if it's not you). I say that because "proxy-surf.loc.cnes.fr" definitively seems like a proxy.

Edit: Myself a French speaker, I checked the tutorial you mentioned and noticed you use buildroot 2020.1 (?). Then you could get away without updating it, however I would really take a look, if I were you, at the other solution provided.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was using buildroot 2020.08 because it was what I was given by a collegue. After some investigation about this error, I determined that it was probably due to my buildroot being out dated (as I said, it was trying to access URLs that didn't exist anymore. In the end, I downloaded the most recent buildroot version I found and it removed those errors ! I had tried updating everything I could before that but nothing would do... Furthermore, I indeed use a proxy in my company. However I cannot do without it as it's a mandatory security :/ Thank you for your help ! :)

Comment: Hi @Lalastro :) If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this !

Answer (score 0):

**CONTEXT**

I was using buildroot 2020.08 because it was what I was given by a collegue. After some investigation about this error, I determined that it was probably due to my buildroot being out dated (as I said, it was trying to access URLs that didn't exist anymore).

**SOLUTION**

I downloaded the most recent buildroot version I found and it removed, if not fixed, the errors and now it's working well !